# Trying to identify this wall type in our apartment

Tags: walls, hanging

I'm trying to put up a mirror (35lbs).

We just moved into this late 1940s co-op we 'bought' last autumn. It is a 4 story building, and other than the updated windows is almost entirely in its original form. Most in between room walls are made from those large plaster panels they would stack to build walls. But there are a few walls, one separates from the next apartment, that is in some kind of... I wanna say concrete. What I need is for those of you who know North American mid-century construction and who can just identify things with a photo to tell me what you think this stuff is.

I've added better photos here because the previous ones were pretty useless. Another power outlet gaveme better shots of what the wall looks like inside.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[![enter image description here][4]][4]

[![enter image description here][5]][5]

Comment: The photos are not very helpful.  It may be helpful to know where in north america you are and what the house looks like in more detail.  Generic answer: Typical US construction is going to be walls made out of wood studs with plaster face.  You use a stud detector to find a stud (and avoid wires) then drill a hole and drive a screw into it to hang your mirror.  Or you could use a suitable anchor and set it into the plaster.

Comment: This isn't plaster. I explained what my apartment is made of in the post. What the photos are of I tried to explain right bfore them.

Comment: Could be cinder blocks.

Comment: Am I correct that what we're looking at here is the view through the space made by studs, to a surface behind the studs?

Comment: No, @Amanda, what we were looking at was past the power outlet into the wall behind it with the plate removed. But I've added new photos now from another outlet that make things more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly cinderblock or concrete masonry units (CMU) where the form is pretty much the same, but the technical difference between "cinderblock" and "concrete block" is whether it was made from fly ash/cinders or concrete. The terms are often conflated in modern use, but cinder block is lighter and softer than concrete block.

The pictures look like what one would expect if the wiring was located in the core holes and a hole into the core had been cut through the side of a block for the receptacle - and the texture of the material is correct.

Pretty clearly NOT structural tile (a third option more common then than now, though it still exists, but has become a high end specialty item as opposed to a common cheap wall with good fire performance.)

Comment: Ok, but despite the difference in makeup, for the purposes of drilling for hanging something are cinderblock and concrete masonry to be treated the same or are there particularities of each that require further definition here in order to know how to proceed?
Could you then suggest something to use to hang my 35lb mirror? I'll add mirror photos.

Comment: ...your question **didn't ask that.** You simply said you were trying to put up a mirror and wondered what wall type this might be, and now you're adding additional questions in comments rather than asking them as related questions. Cinderblock is considerably easier to drill, but the methods and materials are the same.

Comment: You're absolutely right,. my apologies, I was simply continuing the conversation with you since you were so helpful. It was wrong to add on more info. I've removed the reference to the mirror and the photos.
Thank you for the help.

Comment: @tinpanalley please feel free to _first_ browse the site for tips on how to anchor things to a CMU wall (I'm sure you'll find plenty), _then_ if you don't find a satisfactory answer, ask a whole new question (be sure to include links to questions you've reviewed and why they don't answer your question, or it's likely to be closed as a duplicate). We do have a bunch of questions about attaching things to walls 'round these parts...